# Should I be escaping periods in my regular expressions?

Tags: regex, escaping

So I have this regex:

`^Something something something.$`

Should I be preemptively escaping my periods with a backslash or would that be considered pedantic?

Am I wrong to assume that a period in this case is evaluated as a literal period?

Comment: It is necessary, otherwise your regular expressions match things that don't have the full stop.

Comment: Can you provide an example? I'm pretty sure as long as it's not a special part like `.*` that it's treated as a literal period.

Comment: You are not correct. It matches any character except newline, by default. I'd suggest you read up on regex syntax, or use something like http://regex101.com

Comment: Escape all the periods then! Thank you for putting this to bed for me. Please provide this as an answer and I will accept it. I've also updated the question to be more specific and less opinion-based.

Comment: This is in any basic tutorial, it doesn't need yet another Q&A. Next time read the manual.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: I see people making this error all the time, and it doesn't always get corrected in comments.   It could be useful to have something to point to for this very specific issue.

Comment: @AlanMoore it might be useful if it weren't: 1. Completely trivial; and 2. Pretty much impossible to search for unless you already know this is your problem, in which case you don't have a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No regex engine that I know of ever interprets an unescaped period as a literal period. If you want to match a period and nothing else, you must escape it.  Do to otherwise is an error--it's just an error you'll usually get away with, because in most cases where you want to match a literal period, there's little possibility of matching the wrong thing.

There's nothing preemptive about it: always escape the period if you mean to match a period.